# Curved Line Charts

Tags: lightweight-charts

Is it possible to make the set the line charts to have curvature instead of straight lines?

I'm trying to get the desired curved line like the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible right now, but there is an issue for that https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/506, so you can subscribe on it and/or provide additional information to the issue.

Comment: Is this feature available on Technical Analysis Charts?

Comment: @DexterSiah nope.